Office JS Extracting Table Content from Active Slide
I am currently developing an add-in to extract various elements, including shapes, from an active PowerPoint slide. While I have successfully extracted most shapes, I am encountering difficulty when it comes to extracting tables from the slide.
I have gone through the available documentation for the Microsoft PowerPoint API but have not found comprehensive details on handling tables specifically.
Could anyone provide guidance or examples on how to approach this? Any assistance or resources on extracting tables or working with them programmatically would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!
I have tried iterating through the Shapes collection of the active slide using PowerPoint's API, which works well for most shape types like text boxes, etc. However, when it comes to tables, I am unable to retrieve or manipulate them as expected. I was hoping to extract the table's content and properties (e.g., rows, columns, cell values) in a structured format, but I haven't been able to achieve this.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
